# Hope to know that mic is mono or stereo, physically?

Tags: android

I hope to know that mic is mono or stereo.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getSystemAvailableFeatures()
FEATURE_MICROPHONE

It described that device have mic, however, it don't tell us mono or stereo.

Comment: Do you mean one single stereo microphone or recording from two microphones as one stereo pair?

Comment: I mean that 'single stereo microphone' or 'single mono microphone'.

Comment: There's no such thing as a stereo microphone...